# Передача данных по udp на клиент под NAT (C# winforms)

Tags: c#, udp

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли возмлжность передать данные на клиент, который находится под NAT.

Поясню задачу, есть сервер с внешним IP.
Есть клиент под NAT, но с включённым UPNP. Но БЕЗ настроек проброса портов.
Это не широковещание. Это только 1 клиент и только 1 сервер.
Задача, передать на клиент данные (и делать это постояно , тоесть в While(true) {передача}) по UDP.

Подскажите пожалуйста, куда двигаться.

UPDATE////////////////////

По совету товарищей ниже сделал так:
Клиент (за натом) отправляет каждые 5 секунд текст "ПоддержкаСоединения" на сервер (статичный внешний IP за роутером с пробросом портов). Сервер в ответ на это сообщение высылает свои данные.
Серверный код:

```
private void ListenConnectionSupport(ref string itValue, CancellationToken cancelToken)
        {
            IPEndPoint IpEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 13001);
            UdpClient listenClient = new UdpClient(IpEp);
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    IPEndPoint cIpEp=null;
                    byte[] messageBytes = listenClient.Receive(ref cIpEp);
                    if (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messageBytes) == "UDP-support")
                    {
                        itValue = String.Format("{0}:{1}",cIpEp.Address,cIpEp.Port);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
            { }
            finally
            {
                if (listenClient != null)
                    listenClient.Close();
            }

        }

private void SendData(ref Bitmap kadr, ref string kuda, CancellationToken cancelToken)
        {
            UdpClient senderClient = new UdpClient();// (ClientEP);
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(kuda))
                        continue;
                    byte[] testMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(kadr.ToString());

                    string ip = kuda.Split(':')[0];
                    string p = kuda.Split(':')[1];
                    IPEndPoint clientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), int.Parse(p));
                    senderClient.Send(testMessage, testMessage.Length, clientEP);
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
            { }
            finally
            {
                if (senderClient != null)
                    senderClient.Close();
            }
        }
```

Если клиент находится в той же локалке (за тем же роутером), что и сервер, всё ок.
А если клиент через интернет (другой компьютер через мобильный роутер), то серверные сообщения не доходят.

Подскажите!

Comment: Без настроек проброса портов на удп так не выйдет

Comment: Ну видеонаблюдение же как-то передаётся. Должен же быть какой-то способ, задача же типичная.

Comment: Должен, проброс портов или `белый IP` называется. Иначе связь вам с конечным узлом ни как не инициировать с внешней стороны.

Comment: Я ищу способ, как сделать инициатором клиента. только по UDP. В онлайн играх же сделали это.

Comment: Если клиент вызывает сервер, в чем проблема? Сервер получает с помощью `recvfrom()` структуру sockaddr которую и использует при отправке данных клиенту с помощью `sendto()`, и так каждый раз при инициализации соединения от клиента.

Comment: Я ж описал: "А в UDP это будет уже другой экземпляр UDPClient. где гарантия, что ройтер отправив пакет по UDP сразу после этого не забудет, что этот порт надо зарезервировать для ответа клиенту?"

Comment: Вы написали неправильно, у сервера будет открытый сокет с клиентом. Но, следующий пакет тоже должен активировать клиент, или не закрывать соединение, и изображать переодческую активность, чтобы роутер не убил в NAT таблице маршрут.  Другими словами - это не ваша головная боль, а боль NAT таблицы роутера и гейтов, что там по пути стоит :)

Comment: Спасибо, часть уже пашет). Дополнил вопрос, теперь посмотрите пожалуйста, чего я не учёл.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне известно, роутер помнит некоторое время "как пробросил" пакеты, т.е. хранит в таблице соответствия адрес внутреннего IP и порт, который был использован для него. Если эта пара более не используется, то через несколько минут она удаляется из этой таблицы.